# toggleClass again doesn't change icon

Tags: jquery

By clicking a button a class of "fa-minus" is added to a then-appearing div. If fa-minus is clicked then the applied effect is a "line-through" text decoration. At the same time, I want the fa-minus to change to a fa-plus (which later will undo the text deco back to none), which is currently not working:
https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/OjNQop

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fa-minus", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus");     ///// this is not working, the rest of this is fine!!
  $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  $(this).css("color", "gray");
});
```

Comment: It is adding the `fa-plus` class. The problem here is that you aren't removing the `fa-minus` class. Dirty quick fix, but I think you mean something like this: https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/GvqqXy

Comment: The toggleClass ("fa-plus") seems to be working, but it never removes the fa-minus class.

Comment: Just an FYI, you seem to be mixing older versions of jQuery with new ones (`.on`) vs (`.click`).

Comment: @carl-markham i wasn't aware that one is outdated. In free coding camps they teach both for difference scenarios. Which one is recommended ?? Also, I was unaware that i need to remove the old class first. Is that a standard ? I thought it just overwrites it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it does indeed toggle the class `fa-plus`, but the first class stays as `fa-minus`. What you need to do is remove the minus class before adding other icon related classes.

As pointed out by @cjl750 you won't see the class added to extra list items. This is because of your selector `$(".list")`.

You will need to use `$(".list .item")` for the event to work on all list items.

Since your original event is on `fa-minus` you don't need to toggle the class. You could simply just remove the `fa-minus` class and add the `fa-plus` class.

Then you could have an event for the `fa-plus` class which removes that class and adds `fa-minus`. Not the cleanest way of doing it but I leave that up to you.

Comment: Do you see this behavior if you add more than one item to the list? I only see `fa-plus` getting added if you add one item. If you add 2+, I don't see it getting added at all. I was about to post a different answer, but wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: Good shout @cjl750, it doesn't add the class to the other items that are added

Comment: if i do '$('.fa-minus').remove('.fa-minus').toggleClass("fa-plus");' then all the fa-minus' will be removed upon click of a single item. i dont want that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a scope issue going on. I noticed that the problem only happens if you add more than one list item.

If we close off the `#button` click function after this line:

```
$("input[name=checkListItem]").val("").focus();
```

...then we go ahead wrap the final if statement in another click function, so all our click functions are self-contained instead of nested, that solves the problem.

```
$(function() {
  // Hide the container upon ready
  $(".list-container").hide();
  $("hr").hide();

  //* Prevent empty Add from continuing function by Evaluation; It will not accept only spaces; Clear input list once add is clicked; add item & Font Awesome icon to list *//
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name=checkListItem]").val().trim() !== "") {
      var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
      $(".list-container").fadeIn(500);
      $(".list").append(
        '<div class="item"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"/><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
        toAdd +
        "</div>"
      );
    }

    // Focus back on text input once add is clicked
    $("input[name=checkListItem]").val("").focus();

  });

  // click the X icon to remove that item
  $(document).on("click", ".fa-times", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if ($(".fa").length === 0) {
      //If container empty, hide from view
      $(".list-container").hide();
      $("hr").fadeOut(500);
    }
  });

  // click the - icon to cross out that item
  $(".list").on("click", ".fa-minus", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus");
    $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
  });

  //Only show horizontal line if a list is present
  $(document).on("click", ".item", function(){
    if ($(".fa").length === 0) {
      $("hr").hide();
    } else {
      $("hr").fadeIn(500);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you are globalising the click event for `fa-minus`. Meaning any other `fa-minus` elements will inherit the same listener.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is true. I guess I am assuming OP doesn't have `fa-minus` elsewhere on the page, but maybe that is a bad assumption to make. I am trying to figure out how your answer solves that problem, though. Maybe I am just not understanding? I do not see the problem fixed by changing the selector to `.list .item` without changing the nesting.

Comment: correct, only MINUS is added on those list-items until i roll out more functions